# How can I use findviewbyid in static class?

Tags: java

I have a static class:

```
public static void culculateFprice(){
    TextView FinalBuy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buyText);
    int Pprice = MainActivity.pepperoni.getFinalPrice();
    int Cprice = MainActivity.calzone.getFinalPrice();
    int QCprice = MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getFinalPrice();
    int QFprice = MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getFinalPrice();
    int Mprice = MainActivity.mexican.getFinalPrice();
    int FinalPrice = Pprice + Cprice + QCprice + QFprice + Mprice;
    FinalBuy.setText("Стоимось вашего заказа: " + FinalPrice + " руб.");
}
```

How can I use find findViewById in this class?
I call this method from this method

```java
public static void onPlus(int i){
        ArrayList<String> list = listok();
        switch (list.get(i)){
            ...
        }
        adapteR.refreshData(listokadd());
        culculateFprice();
    }
```

And have problem "Non-static method "findViewById(int)" cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Does this answer your question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761366/can-not-find-a-view-with-findviewbyid

Comment: No, I have a problem , b=not in onCreat, i have problem in static class "Non-static method "findViewById(int)" cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe your problem better. First you say you have a static class, but only show a static method. Then you say you get a NullPointException (do you mean NullPointerException? Be precise!), then you say it's a compiler error ("non-static method..."). Make up your mind! A [mcve] would help a lot. Nobody knows what `findViewById` is. See also [ask].

Comment: Done, I rewrite question. Check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this function exists in your `Activity` class and you would like to process some information based on the `View`. There are two ways you can solve this:

1. Remove the static modifier and let the instance take care of this.
2. Create a field that holds a `View` reference that gets created as soon as your layout is set.

So your `Activity` will hold the field:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    static View FinalBuy; // needs to be static, otherwise would give same error
}
```

```
@Override
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    // after setLayout
    FinalBuy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buyText);
}
```

But to save your code from a potential runtime error, use an `if...else` block in your static method:

```
public static void culculateFprice(){
    if(FinalBuy != null) {
        // your code here.
    }
}
```

This problem is basic Java and not Android. That is how Java language is designed to provide instance vs. static methods for the programs.

This `static View` declaration leads to a potential design flaw because this `View` will outlive the Activity. Instead of this, you should consider using the approach I suggested in the list as option 1 and see why you are unable to use an instance method in your program. You should read more on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107165/is-it-a-good-idea-to-declare-static-view-in-android/50055614).

*This will likely need you to change your other fields of `MainActivity` to be declared as non-static as well!*